# Why is this Java tutorial code from Oracle returning errors?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am in the first stages of learning Java using the tutorials from Oracle. I am using the Intellij IDEA Java IDE. The code for Lesson Two B (found here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/prog-140388.html) is:

```
class LessonTwoB {

    String text = "I'm a Simple Program";
    static String text2 = "I'm static text";

    String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    String getStaticText(){
        return text2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        LessonTwoB progInstance = new LessonTwoB();
        String retrievedText = progInstance.getText();
        String retrievedStaticText =
                progInstance.getStaticText();
        System.out.println(retrievedText);
        System.out.println(retrievedStaticText);
    }
}
```

When I run this code it returns an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleProgram
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code cannot throw that exception.  When you think you are invoking your program, IDEA is attempting to start something else called `ExampleProgram`

Comment: The JVM complains about not finding `ExampleProgram` which is nowhere mentioned in the code you posted. It's probably your run configuration in IDEA that is messed up.

Comment: Indeed, I am still learning how the interface works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, if you run a class called `ExampleProgram`, delete it, then just click `run`, you will get exactly that error. By default, the IDE attempts to run the last class you used.

The solution is

- Click the "Run" menu item (not the green triangle),
- Select the "Run..." option,
- Choose `LessonTwoB` from the dropdown menu.

Comment: @user6145662 No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij is trying to run a class that no longer exists.

Try this:

- Right click on `LessonTwoB` in the project explorer on the left

  [image]
- Select "Run 'LessonTwoB.main()" in the context menu

  [image]